# A sum on co-prime positive integers with different parity

Tags: number-theory, summation, divisor-sum

I was trying to see that if the sums like the following is calculable

$$\sum_{(x, y)=1} f(x,y)$$

where $x>y$ are positive integers with different parity. How can we prove that the sum is divergent or convergent? Like the following

$$\sum_{(x, y)=1} \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} $$

Actually, what I'm looking for is to see that if the sum is convergent, how can we calculate it? Like

$$\sum \frac{x^2}{x^4+y^4}$$

Comment: What do you mean by different parity?

Comment: One of $x$ and $y$ is odd and other is even.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Since $\gcd(n,1)=1$ for any positive integer $n$, the sum contains $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}$

Also, we have $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{1-1/k^2}{1+1/k^2}=1\neq 0$

---

One could also argue that since we're summing over all coprime tuples of $\Bbb Z^2$, for $\gcd(x,y)=1$, the term $\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is cancelled out by the term $\dfrac{y^2-x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ which is from the tuple $(y,x)$ since $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(y,x)$, so the overall sum is $0$.

Hence, my original answer assumes (wlog?) that $x\gt y$ (i.e., the tuple $(x,y)$ is assumed to be the same as $(y,x)$, so we only take the tuple $(x,y)$ in the sum) to show divergence.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have mentioned $x>y$. Actually I wanted to see if the sum is convergent, then can we find a way to calculate it?

Comment: @Ghartal, If $x\gt y$, then my answer shows that the sum is divergent. Read the answer again more carefully.

Comment: Yeah, I know:) Your answer is correct. But look at my edit. If the summand was an expression that made sum convergent, how could we calculate it? Like $$\frac{x^2}{x^4+y^4}$$Or any other expression that is easy to handle.

Comment: @Prasun Your first argument is totally fine but in the second argument where you said they get cancelled out so the sum is zero. My point here is you can not rearrange them. Rearranging them will give any number you want because this is not absolutely convergent